# Switch-Case to count occurrence of integer values

Tags: c++

Here's another problem I have been working on.  This is purely for educational purposes, and I understand that it is probably not the most efficient way to execute this objective.

The goal is to read a user's input in the console/terminal (are these synonymous?), and count the occurrence of the integer values `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` using a `switch-case` construction.

As currently constructed, I'm storing the user input as a character value, and comparing each character to the integers in character form (e.g. '0', '1'...).

When I run my code, after entering an example such as `1235000`, I get zero values for everything.  However, if I initiate the input with a character, such as `a000125`, the program executes correctly.

What is going on here, and how should I resolve this?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int zeros=0;
    int ones=0;
    int twos=0;
    int threes=0;
    int fours=0;
    int others=0;

    int num;
    printf("please enter a positive integer\n ");
    scanf_s("%d",&num);
    
    while ((num = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        switch (num)
        {
        case '0':
            zeros++;
            break;
        case '1':
            ones++;
            break;
        case '2':
            twos++;
            break;
        case '3':
            threes++;
            break;
        case '4':
            fours++;
            break;
        default:
            others++;
        }
    }

    printf("the number of zeros is %d\n", zeros);
    printf("the number of ones is %d\n", ones);
    printf("the number of twos is %d\n", twos);
    printf("the number of threes is %d\n", threes);
    printf("the number of fours is %d\n", fours);
    printf("other characters/numbers: %d\n", others);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are getting the user input twice, once with `scanf_s` and once with (repeated calls to) `getchar`.  As written, the `getchar` result replaces the `scanf_s` result, the scanf result is never used in any way.  Make up your mind and use just one of these.

Comment: If you input an integer, you will realize that the code requires a little more sophistication than what you've attempted, since you are not dealing with a string.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's it.  Problem solved.  Thank you for humbling me.